# Can I share BitMap as an image (PNG, JPG...) on Facebook, Twitter etc

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I need to give the user possibility to share his high score. I took an image (PNG) and wrote the high score on it on it. Can I convert BitMap to PNG and share it without saving the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `boolean compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)` of the `Bitmap` class.

```
ByteArrayOutputStram baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] png = baos.toByteArray();
```

You will have the `byte[]` contained the image in png format. You can then use any API you want to share that image.